# A function making an upper limit for figures in one of the rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel table as follows:

```
 6000       7000
12000      14000
18000      21000
30000      35000
42000      49000
```

With the number of lines equal to 9 or more. I would like to rearrange the table such that in the second row all figures greater than 30000 would be replaced by 30000. In the third row the figures stay the same as they are. That is, after the transformation, the table will look as follows:

```
 6000       7000
12000      14000
18000      21000
30000      35000
30000      49000
```

What function can do that?

Comment: Your description of the rows to be changed does not match your example data. Please [edit] the question and clarify. Perhaps you meant to say 1st column and 2nd column instead of 2nd row and 3rd row?

Answer (score 2):

First right click the first column in your table, right click and click Insert. And now in the new column which is inserted, type the formula in the first cell:

```
=IF(A1>30000,30000,A1)
```

Replace A1 with the first cell in your table.

Then drag using the right-bottom corner of the cell to the rest cell in the temporary second column.

Then right-click the first column and click Delete to delete the first column.

Comment: Please don't answer until the question is clarified. His example data does not match his description of what he wants. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill the same formula will apply on the second column, just we need to change the name of first Cell.

Comment: Yeah, but the text in the question is referring to **rows** not **columns**

Comment: @DavidPostill also that can be many users confuse Row and Columns, but the description example expresses it strongly. Perhaps ask the OP and edit the question?

Comment: I already did. See my comment on the question ...

Comment: Please don't make trivial edits on closed questions. The edit on the closed post has wasted its one chance at the reopen review queue. If the OP now edits in the requested data, it will not go through the queue again.